# How to use same pattern with multiples occurrences?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to extract text from my changelog to put it in a variable.

But i can't tell to sed/awk that i want the text between the first and the second occurrence of my pattern.

Here is my changelog:

```
This is the changelog of the application
You may find Features and Bug Fixes

# [1.5.0]() (2019-08-20)

### Fixes

- **iOS** Correct some display bugs

# [1.4.0]() (2019-08-15)

### Features

- **Options** New function

...
```

I want the output to be:

```
# [1.5.0]() (2019-08-20)

### Fixes

- **iOS** Correct some display bugs
```

I already tried:

```
sed -n '/# \[/,/# \[/p; /# \[/q' CHANGELOG.md

# [1.5.0]() (2019-08-20)


awk '/# \[/ && ++n == 2, /# \[/' < CHANGELOG.md

# [1.4.0]() (2019-08-15)
```

I use `'# \['` as my pattern. Anyone can help?

Comment: `awk` would probably be better suited than `sed` for that. That said I'm more familiar with antiquated `sed` commands than with `awk`, so all I can suggest is `sed -n '/^# \[/{:l;p;n;/^# \[/q;bl}'` (if the current line is a version line, loop printing lines until you reach another version line, at which point you quit)

Comment: Sorry but when I try this i got `sed: 1: "/^# \[/{:l;p;n;/^# \[/q ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`

Comment: Try `sed -n '/^# \[/{P;:s n;/^# \[/q;p;bs}' file`, it works even with `--posix` option.

Comment: Which `sed` are you using? I've double checked and it [works fine](https://ideone.com/VqPMyZ) with modern GNU sed

Comment: Does it have to be set/awk? Here is a solution with Ruby: `ruby -n -W -e 'puts $_ if /^# \[/../^# \[/' <CHANGELOG.md `. The drawback is that the useful `..` operator has been declared deprecated by the Gods of Ruby recently, and while the command still works with the most recent Ruby version, there is the possibility that it will stop working some time in the future, after an update in Ruby.

Comment: @Kwoak Which one works for you?

Comment: This one : `sed -n '/^# \[/{:l;p;n;/^# \[/q;bl}'` i just was using the wrong `sed`

Comment: @user1934428 The flip-flop operator [has been undeprecated](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/cjk8e1/undeprecate_flipflop/?ref=readnext), as far as I understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following GNU `sed` command :

```
sed -n '/^# \[/{:l;p;n;/^# \[/q;bl}'
```

Explanation :

- `-n` : do not print lines by default
- `/^# \[/{...}` : when a version line is encountered, execute the commands inside `{...}`
- `:l` : label l, denoting the start of a loop
- `p;n` : print the current line, start working on the next line
- `/^# \[/q` if that next line is a version line, have `sed` exit
- `bl` : (otherwise) jump to the label l, looping until a version line is encountered